# In Java, using && operator, would it compute all instances and determine in the end or once it find a false, it would immediately return false

Tags: java, operators

I am wondering if I write a line of code:

```
return bool1 && bool2 && bool3
```

where

```
bool1 = false
bool2 = true
bool3 = true
```

Would Java immediately return a false after seeing bool1 is false and do not look at bool2 and bool3? Or would it compute one by one from the left handside?

Comment: Single & has different meaning in Java

Comment: @Ivar YES!! This is exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses short circuit AND (&&).

Meaning that if bool1 is false it will not evaluate bool2 and bool3.